# ASP.NET Buttons not showing Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, parameters

I seem to be having a problem with my local machine.

When loading a page that has a Button on it, and the button has been set with the parameters from the header, on my local machine the parameters disappear, but on our development box they are still there.

This is hard to explain, so I will show with an image.

This is what the button looks like when I hover over it with the mouse, coming from our Development server, which is II7:

[alt text http://members.generationdub.com/footose/params.jpg](http://members.generationdub.com/footose/params.jpg)

This is the same exact code on my local machine (also running IIS7), but as you can see, the parameters are not "set" on the button.

[alt text http://members.generationdub.com/footose/noparam.jpg](http://members.generationdub.com/footose/noparam.jpg)

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it? The web.config's are identical, so I think it may be an IIS problem?

Comment: Is the header set conditionally? If so, the condition could be true on development, making the button show link with parameters & not on the local machine.

Comment: Please be specific. What are the "parameters" that are set? What property are you referring to? What is the type of your button? asp:Button? asp:LinkButton? What "header" are you referring to?

Comment: Please post the part of the markup or codebehind where this parameters are getting set?